# Open a new window (or new tab) programmatically instead of always a popup

Tags: angularjs, popup, window, window.open

I'm trying to create a new Window with AngularJS

```
var _url = 'http://extern.com/index.html'; 
$window.open(_url);
```

It always opens a pop-up window, but never a normal window or a new tab. Why?

I use Angular 1.2.9 with Chrome, Firefox and IE10.

My problem is only the chrome 34!

Comment: have a look at the docu [here](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/window.htm#open) and fiddle around with second parameters "_blank, _parent, _self and _top"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$window.open` is really just the same as `window.open`, which doesn't have much to do with angular. In terms of opening in a new window or tab, that is up to the user, and the settings they have initialised with their browser.

Also the same goes for anchor links with `target="_blank"`.

Comment: Where can you set the browser in?

Comment: I guess it depends on your browser, and shouldn't be too hard to google. I believe there are also plugins for browsers than can manipulate the tab/popup processes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _url = 'http://extern.com/index.html'; 
var tabWindowId = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
tabWindowId.location.href = _url;
```

Comment: While this code may work, it is much appreciated at Stack Overflow when you add some explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var _url = 'http://extern.com/index.html'; 

window.location.href = _url;
```

Comment: I am able to open in a new tab using location in angular js , i posted as an answer ,not a comment

Comment: @parsh: Your solution is simply pointing the browser to a new url using `window.location.href` instead of `window.open` or `$window.open`. How does this open a new tab?